# Code not recognizing ColumnDataSource for what it is

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh, panel-pyviz

I want to change the data source of a simple line plot depending on what the user picks from a dropdown menu.

I have 2 dataframes, the weight and age of myself and my boyfriend.

```
my_weight = [60,65,70] 
my_age = [21,22,25]

d_weight = [65,70,80] 
d_age = [21,22,25]

me = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(my_weight, my_age)), 
               columns =['weight', 'age'], index=None) 

dillon = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(d_weight, d_age)), 
               columns =['weight', 'age'], index=None)
```

I turn these two dataframe into ColumnDataSource objects, create my plot and line, add my dropdown and jslink. There is also a demo slider to show how I can change the line_width of my line.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.core.properties import Any, Bool, ColumnData

pn.extension()

source = ColumnDataSource(me, name="Me")
source2 = ColumnDataSource(dillon, name="Dillon")
# print("Me: ", source.data, "Dillon: ", source2.data)

plot = figure(width=300, height=300)
myline = plot.line(x='weight', y='age', source=source, color="pink")

width_slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='Line Width', start=0.1, end=10)
width_slider.jslink(myline.glyph, value='line_width')

dropdown2 = pn.widgets.Select(name='Data', options=[source, source2])
dropdown2.jslink(myline, value='data_source')

pn.Column(dropdown2, width_slider, plot)
```

When I run this code, I get the error

`ValueError: expected an instance of type DataSource, got ColumnDataSource(id='5489', ...) of type str`

with the error occurring from the `dropdown2` section of code.

Whats preventing the code from recognizing source and source2 as ColumnDataSource() objects?
What is meant by got ColumnDataSource(id='5489', ...) **of type str**? How is it a string?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here. The first is that the `Select` widget does not actually make complex objects available in Javascript, so callbacks that try to access those models in a JS callback will not work. The only solution therefore is to write an actual JS callback and provide the actual models as `args`. The secondary complication here is that the two data sources contain different columns, specifically the 'Me' `ColumnDataSource` contains an age column and the 'Dillon' data source contains a height column. This means you also need to update the glyph to look at those different sources. In practice this looks like this:

```
import panel as pn

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d
from bokeh.core.properties import Any, Bool, ColumnData

source = ColumnDataSource(me, name="Me")
source2 = ColumnDataSource(dillon, name="Dillon")

plot = figure(width=300, height=300)
myline = plot.line(x='weight', y='age', source=source, color="pink")

width_slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='Line Width', start=1, end=10)
width_slider.jslink(myline.glyph, value='line_width')
dropdown2 = pn.widgets.Select(name='Data', options={'Me': source, 'Dillon': source2})

code = """
if (cb_obj.value == 'Me') {
  myline.data_source = source
  myline.glyph.y = {'field': 'age'}

} else {
  myline.data_source = source2
  myline.glyph.y = {'field': 'height'}
}
"""
dropdown2.jscallback(args={'myline': myline, 'source': source, 'source2': source2}, value=code)
```

That being said, the way I would recommend to implement this in Panel is this:

```
dropdown2 = pn.widgets.Select(name='Data', options={'Me': me, 'Dillon': dillon}, value=me)
width_slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='Line Width', start=1, end=10)

@pn.depends(dropdown2)
def plot(data):
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)
    plot = figure(width=300, height=300)
    column = 'age' if 'age' in source.data else 'height'
    myline = plot.line(x='weight', y=column, source=source, color="pink")
    width_slider.jslink(myline.glyph, value='line_width')
    return plot

pn.Column(dropdown2, width_slider, plot).embed()
```

Finally, if you're willing to give [hvPlot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/) a go, this can be further reduced to:

```
import hvplot.pandas

dropdown2 = pn.widgets.Select(name='Data', options={'Me': me, 'Dillon': dillon}, value=me)
width_slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='Line Width', start=1, end=10)

@pn.depends(dropdown2)
def plot(data):
    p = data.hvplot('weight', color='pink')
    width_slider.jslink(p, value='glyph.line_width')
    return p

pn.Column(dropdown2, width_slider, plot).embed()
```

Comment: Thanks, @philippjfr . Just wondering - has 'jscallback' been deprecated? It neither works with Select nor Button objects.

Comment: What version of Panel do you have? It wasn't added until Panel 0.7.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to the Panel abstractions on top of Bokeh, but it's worth mentionfing that actual Bokeh sliders cannot have complicated things such a `ColumnDataSource` as the `options` value. Only simple types such a numbers, strings etc. As it happens, this:

> ColumnDataSource(id='5489', ...)

Is the "repr" for a CDS, i.e. if you try to print a CDS that the string that is generated. So my guess is that Panel is somewhere converting the CDS to its string representation, and passing that string to the underlying Bokeh `Select` widge. That is not going to do what you want of course.

There may be a better Panel-specific way to do things, but one approach is to get the underlying Bokeh `Select` widget, then call `js_on_change` to add a `CustomJS` callback that updates the data. There are lots of examples you an emulate in in the [JavaScript Callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html) chapter of the docs.